# How to combine Two if statements in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2="UKPE52 - High Earners- 15% Contribution-0-3",  
B2="UKPE91 - Opt out -15% High Earner Cash Allowance -0-3",  
B2="UKPE55 - 10K Cap Pen Sal – 15% Contribution-0-3", 
B2="UKPE56 - 10K Cap Pen Sal - 7 % Contribution -4"),  
OR(C2=0, C2=1, C2=2, C2=3)), "match", "no match")
```

```
=IF(AND(OR(B2="UKPE51 - UK Normal Employee - 7% Contribution 4-10",  
B2="UKPE57 - Opt out  - (0% Contribution No Cash Allowance ) 4-10",  
B2="UKPE56 - 10K Cap Pen Sal - 7 % Contribution -4"),  
OR(C2=4, C2=5, C2=6, C2=7, C2=8, C2=9, C2="UK - 999 - Maidenhead",  
C2=10)), "match", "no match")
```

Comment: Combine by AND or OR? And why can't you do it?

Comment: I am voting to close this question has the OP has not given any explation on what he/she is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Using a text editor that has "parenthese matching" is helpful (e.g. "Kate").

Then; by spreading out the formulas over several lines,
with indentation on the items inside the parentheses,
it is easier to see the "structure":

First IF

```
=IF(
    AND(
        OR(
            B2="UKPE52 - High Earners- 15% Contribution-0-3", 
            B2="UKPE91 - Opt out -15% High Earner Cash Allowance -0-3", 
            B2="UKPE55 - 10K Cap Pen Sal – 15% Contribution-0-3", 
            B2="UKPE56 - 10K Cap Pen Sal - 7 % Contribution -4"), 
            OR(
                C2=0, 
                C2=1, 
                C2=2, 
                C2=3)
            ),
    "match", 
    "no match"
    )
```

Second IF

```
=IF(
    AND(
        OR(
            B2="UKPE51 - UK Normal Employee - 7% Contribution 4-10", 
            B2="UKPE57 - Opt out - (0% Contribution No Cash Allowance ) 4-10", 
            B2="UKPE56 - 10K Cap Pen Sal - 7 % Contribution -4"), 
            OR(
                C2=4, 
                C2=5, 
                C2=6, 
                C2=7, 
                C2=8, 
                C2=9, 
                C2="UK - 999 - Maidenhead", 
                C2=10)
        ), 
        "match", 
        "no match")
```

Both `AND(`'s can be removed as they have only a single `OR(` as argument; so no "AND" is required.

After that, there is a single `OR(` as conditional expression in both `IF(`'s.

So we end up with this conditional expression:

```
OR(
        OR(
            B2="UKPE52 - High Earners- 15% Contribution-0-3", 
            B2="UKPE91 - Opt out -15% High Earner Cash Allowance -0-3", 
            B2="UKPE55 - 10K Cap Pen Sal – 15% Contribution-0-3", 
            B2="UKPE56 - 10K Cap Pen Sal - 7 % Contribution -4"), 
            OR(
                C2=0, 
                C2=1, 
                C2=2, 
                C2=3)
    ,
        OR(
            B2="UKPE51 - UK Normal Employee - 7% Contribution 4-10", 
            B2="UKPE57 - Opt out - (0% Contribution No Cash Allowance ) 4-10", 
            B2="UKPE56 - 10K Cap Pen Sal - 7 % Contribution -4"), 
            OR(
                C2=4, 
                C2=5, 
                C2=6, 
                C2=7, 
                C2=8, 
                C2=9, 
                C2="UK - 999 - Maidenhead", 
                C2=10)
    )
```

... which is likely to be reducible - but I'll stop there as the goal has been reached,
and as it might be easier to expand on in this state, if needed.